# AJAX reloads the page without inserting into database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am new to Ajax and confused. The problem is the ajax reloads the page. The function mentioned in the url inserts the data into database. but the page reloads. I guess the URL is not working but i am not sure on this.

Here is my Controller Function

```
public function insert_student_fee_payment()
{
    $std_code=$this->input->post('std_code');
    $total_fee=$this->input->post('total_fee');
    $payable_fee=$this->input->post('payable_fee');
    $date=date('Y m d');

    $class_detail=$this->db->select('class.class_year,class.class_semester')
    ->join('class','class_student.class_id=class.class_id','LEFT')
    ->where('class_student.student_id',$std_code)
    ->where('class_student.class_student_status',2)
    ->limit(1)
    ->get('class_student')
    ->result();

    if(count($class_detail)>0)
    {
        foreach($class_detail as $cd)
        {
            $year=$cd->class_year;
            $semester=$cd->class_semester;
        }
    }

    $data=array(
    'std_code'=>$std_code,
    'year'=>$year,
    'semester'=>$semester,
    'total_fee'=>$total_fee,
    'payable_fee'=>$payable_fee,
    'date'=>$date,
    'status'=>2
    );

    if($this->db->insert('student_fees',$data))
    {
        echo '1';
    }


}
```

and here is my Ajax code in form

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#insert_fee_payment').click(function(){

var std_code=$('#std_code').text();
var total_fee=$('#total_fee').text().split(' ');
var payable_fee=$('#payable_fee').text().split(' ');
total_fee=total_fee[0];
payable_fee=payable_fee[0];

var data='std_code='+std_code+'&total_fee='+total_fee+'&payable_fee='+payable_fee;
$.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url()."index.php/finance/insert_student_fee_payment;?>',
        type: 'POST',   
        data: data,
        success: function(response)
        {
          alert(response);     
        },
        error: function(response,status,err)
        {
          alert(err.message);
        }
}); 

});  
});
```

any help guys

Comment: try to change url in ajax request :- url: 'finance/insert_student_fee_payment'

Comment: tried possible variations but not worked.

Comment: try to test it by giving hardcore url where you can make request? can you used base_url() ?

Comment: Yes Here is the URL url: '<?php echo base_url()."index.php/finance/insert_student_fee_payment;?>',

Comment: can you try removing index.php from your url ?

Comment: Problem solved. The column name in my db was wrong. But any how debugging was issue. The return false after the ajax call allows to see the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add return false after the error function.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#insert_fee_payment').click(function(){

    var std_code=$('#std_code').text();
    var total_fee=$('#total_fee').text().split(' ');
    var payable_fee=$('#payable_fee').text().split(' ');
    total_fee=total_fee[0];
    payable_fee=payable_fee[0];

    var data='std_code='+std_code+'&total_fee='+total_fee+'&payable_fee='+payable_fee;
     $.ajax({
    url: '/index.php/finance/insert_student_fee_payment',
    type: 'POST',   
    data: data,
    success: function(response)
    {
      alert(response);     
    },
    error: function(response,status,err)
    {
      alert(err.message);
    }
    return false;
    }); 

    });  
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

We don't see the HTML so it's hard to say what's wrong but my guess is that `$('#insert_fee_payment')` is a submit button so you have to cancel the action by default which is submitting the form.

```
$('#insert_fee_payment').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
};
```

or

```
$('#insert_fee_payment').click(function(){

var std_code=$('#std_code').text();
var total_fee=$('#total_fee').text().split(' ');
var payable_fee=$('#payable_fee').text().split(' ');
total_fee=total_fee[0];
payable_fee=payable_fee[0];

var data='std_code='+std_code+'&total_fee='+total_fee+'&payable_fee='+payable_fee;
$.ajax({
        url: '/index.php/finance/insert_student_fee_payment',
        type: 'POST',   
        data: data,
        success: function(response)
        {
          alert(response);     
        },
        error: function(response,status,err)
        {
          alert(err.message);
        }
}); 
return false;
});
```